# Snowflake and Google Authentication Limitations

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I just set up my snowflake instance to use google auth.  I can log in with my google account, query tables, create roles, etc...  Today I ran into an issue (two of them actually).

I run this script

```
SET ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;
CREATE WAREHOUSE IF NOT EXISTS joe;
```

When I am logged in with my Google Account, I get the error message:
`SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on account 'XXX99999'`

When I am logging in with my Snowflake native account, it works.  Both accounts have the ACCOUNTADMIN role and are using it.

This is all in the classic interface.   When trying to switch over to Snowsight, my google account cannot login in.  I click the [Authenticate with Google] and the screen refreshes, no error, but not now the button is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

For the first error, the reason is that the user does not have any roles that has the privileges on the account where the operation is being done. To overcome that you need to assign the right set of roles to the user coming from Google IDP.

Please check the following documentation which details the levels for each of the database objects that requires privileges: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html#syntax

For the second issue, which button is disabled "Snowsight" which is listed from Classic UI?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below scripts to create warehouse. You need to use role instead of set role.

use ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN; //To use accountadmin role

CREATE WAREHOUSE IF NOT EXISTS joe_wh; //to creare warehouse

To use SSO based login with Snowsight, Please migrate to advanced SAML as per

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-advanced.html#migrating-to-a-saml2-security-integration